# Motorola G40 Fusion Display Issue: Power Button Not Turning On Display in Android 14 Custom ROMs

Tags: android, open-source, android-source, motorola, lineageos

I have been making custom roms device source for my motorola g40 fusion since android 13. The display had no issues in android 13. But since android 14, the powerbutton wouldnt work to turn on display after it turn off in system. It can used to force reboot or go to fastboot but the display wont turn on in system. I can hear notification and other stuff from the device tho i am not sure if the touch works or no. The only hack i have found for now is to disable dynamic refresh rate in the [kernel source and force a single refresh rate](https://github.com/moto-hanoip/android_kernel_motorola_msm-4.14/commit/8d5ac26bfb166856fd10c86d00f444782f51dfc6). I could not find any fix in any similar devices or devices with same chipset. So any help would be appreciated.

1. [Logs](https://katb.in/buledodecov)
2. [Video](https://imgur.com/a/73qSbtF)

Device sources:

1. [Device tree](https://github.com/anoosragh69/device_motorola_hanoip)
2. [Vendor tree](https://github.com/anoosragh69/android_vendor_motorola_hanoip)
3. [Kernel tree](https://github.com/moto-hanoip/android_kernel_motorola_msm-4.14)

I have tried to use stock hwcomposer, tried giving permissions to some brightness nodes. Reverting some commits related to secondary displays in frameworks/native which i thought may have been the cause.